# UIView.animateWithDuration:animations:completion: gets canceled in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, xctest

I'm trying to unit test an extension on `UIView`, which calls `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`.

Unfortunately all animations in the test case gets canceled immediately and therefore the `isFinished` parameter of the completion block is always `false`.

Does anyone have an idea how to get animations working in a test case?

This is my playground code:

```swift
import UIKit
import XCTest

extension UIView {
    func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       animations: {
                            self.alpha = 0.0
                       },
                       completion: { isFinished in
                            self.isHidden = isFinished

                            completion?(isFinished)
                       })
    }
}

class UIViewTests: XCTestCase {

    func testFadeView() {
        // Given
        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Expect completion handler to be called.")

        let view = UIView()
        view.alpha = 1.0

        // When
        print("Date before", Date())
        view.fadeOut(duration: 1.0) { (isFinished) in
            print("Date completed", Date())
            print("isFinished", isFinished)

            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        // Then
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1.1)

        XCTAssertTrue(view.isHidden) // <- this assertion always fails, cause `isFinished` inside the completion handler is always `false`.
        XCTAssertEqual(view.alpha, 0.0, accuracy: CGFloat.ulpOfOne)
    }
}

UIViewTests.defaultTestSuite.run()
```

The assertion `XCTAssertTrue(view.isHidden)` always fails. Furthermore the log statements output:

```
Date before 2019-05-20 23:30:35 +0000
Date completed 2019-05-20 23:30:35 +0000
```

So basically the animation is killed immediately.

Comment: Please share code

Comment: Sorry, I've added a playground example 

Comment: So from your previous description: your actual test isn't calling animate, right? Instead, it calls your extension? It's challenging to tell from the code you added.

Comment: Yeah, I've copied the code from the extension directly to the test case, to keep it simpler.

Comment: Basically, I'd like to see the code you want to test.

Comment: I've updated the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the animation to complete with the correct flag, the view needs to in a UIWindow that is visible.

```
let window = UIWindow()
window.addSubview(view)
window.isHidden = false
```

With this, your test succeeds. But UIKit won't clean up the window without giving the run loop an extra kick at the very end of the test. So add

```
func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date())
}
```

Then the window (and anything in it) will be deallocated.

Now that it's working, you can save time by reducing your duration. I got the test down to 23ms by using `duration: 0.001`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It seems like the view has to be attached to a `UIWindow` which is currently visible, in order for the animation to work.

```
let window = UIWindow()
window.makeKeyAndVisible()

let view = UIView()
window.addSubview(view)
```

also worked. 
Anyhow, I don't want to create a second key-window, so I've gone with `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` (which has less optionals) instead.

Again thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Excellent follow-up. I'm going to update my answer with your information, so that it's easier for other readers.